# Hypervisor literature

Tags: c, embedded, hypervisor

I have been looking for literature covering the mechanics behind a hypervisor/microkernel that explains how it works, the design behind etc but can´t find anything except published cs papers and wikipedia.

I'm very interested in this field and would like to know more, so im wondering if anyone could recommend any literature in this area? The closest that I can think of is books covering operating systems.

I´m mostly interested in the added security benefits a hypervisor can provide for a OS instead of the running several OS´s on top of a hypervisor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The hypervisor topic is closely knit with the hardware used along with it.
So it is difficult to find out the hypervisor explanation without knowing hardware details.

So if the hypervisor is implemented on ARMv7, you need to look the hypervisor implementation along with the hardware support e.g. virtualization extension or security extension provided by hardware.

A good writeup is available on 
[genode web page](http://genode.org/documentation/articles/arm_virtualization)
You will find article on security extension also there.

This documentation is targeted for ARMv7 hardware.

ARMv7 Cortex A : architecture reference manual will provide more details of hardware support required for hypervisor.